# Configuring nginx virtual hosts

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I'm having trouble configuring nginx virtual hosts on a Debian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy) machine.

All I get is a 500 Internal Server Error.

Here is an example of my vhost_autogen.conf file:

```
server {
  listen                *:80;

  server_name           api-dev.domain.com;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/api-dev.domain.com.access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/api-dev.domain.com.error.log;

  location / {
    root  /code/api.domain.com/public;
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  }

  location ~ \.php$ {
    root  /code/api.domain.com/public;
    try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    index  index.html index.htm index.php;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param APP_ENV dev;

    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
  }

}
```

Permission issue is almost certainly is not, since I gave full permissions (777), just to be sure.

Any hints?

Here is the error log:

```
2013/12/22 17:08:11 [error] 4341#0: *16 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 192.168.56.1, server: api-dev.domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "api-dev.domain.com"
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Are there any relevant messages in your logs?

Comment: Added to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have wrong `try_files` inside both of your `location` blocks.

```
try_files  $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
```

When it hits `$uri/` this causes nginx to look for every file specified in the `index` directive. It hits on `index.php`, goes to your second `location`, and that's where it seems to get stuck in a loop.

I would rewrite these as:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
}
```

The second `location` does not need an `index` directive at all.

Comment: As soon as I get home I'll do the modifications you referred and see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: Hi. It returns a 404 now.

Comment: ah damn disregard that last comment. When changing the file I modified the path (that was embarrassing). It works now. Thanks for the help.